# Javascript add node

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes

So I have a function like such:

```
var elem = document.createElement( 'svg' );
elem.id  = 'svg1';
```

and I would like to, in a later function, be able to grab this element via `document.getElementById('svg1')`.

I have found this does not work, and through some research, aka google, found that adding an element this way does not actually add it to the 'node tree'. How can I create an element so I can later reference the Id?

Comment: Why don't you just keep a reference to the variable?

Comment: looks like you stopped googling too soon. Append the node to the document. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml. JQuery also simplifies this. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: I also would recommend looking into jQuery. Makes DOM manipulations a breeze.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add it to the DOM. For example, to add it as a child of an element with an ID "parent":

```
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(elem);
```

Answer (score 5):

To add an element to the DOM you do this:

```
document.body.appendChild(elem);
```

That adds the object to the BODY. If you want to add the node to another node, you replace `body` with `getElementById("id")`.